# Запрет на удаление записей

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер, constraints

Нужно запретить удаление записей из таблицы, не удовлетворяющих определенному условию с помощью триггера. Без использования представления и `INSTEAD OF`.

У меня проблема в том, что при обнаружении записи, не удовлетворяющий условие я вызываю `raise_application_error`. Но при удалении сразу нескольких вариантов одним `delete`, где какие-то варианты можно удалить, а остальные нет, триггер сразу выдаёт исключение и ничего не удаляет.

Comment: Ну-ну... ну нельзя быть немножко беременной. Не может запрос на  одну половину выполняться, а на вторую выдавать ошибку. Не, можно, конечно, в AFTER DELETE взять да и повставлять удалённые, но которые удалять не надо, записи обратно в таблицу... но не бред ли?

Comment: _**Нужно запретить** удаление записей из таблицы, не удовлетворяющих определенному условию **с помощью триггера**_ - а почему вы считаете, что нужно запретить именно с помощью триггера? Ведь логически напрашиваестся простое решение - записи из таблицы, не удовлетворяющие определенному условию, не удалять вообще.

Comment: Соглашусь с @Akina. Нужно или запрещать удаление или втихую удаления игнорировать. Смешивать - не рационально. Когда delete неявно игнорирует часть найденных данных, не бросая исключения, но при попытке построчного удаления будет бросать исключение - это непоследовательно. Можно, конечно, перейти от запрета к эмуляции игнорирования удаления, тогда удаление одиночные и групповые будут работать единообразно.

Comment: А чем вызвана попытка вандальных действий по отношению к вопросу?

Answer (score 3):

Лучшее решение будет - проверять условие на удаление записей до начала выполнения DML.

---

Но допустим, что нужна "защита от дурака" и надо не допустить удаления записей. Например, записи содержащие префикс `'**'` в одном из столбцов. Надо тогда логгировать исключения с [error_logging_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__BGBDIGAH). Полное предложение DML, в этом случае, выполнится. Вот так:

```sql
create table t1 as
select rownum id, case when mod (rownum, 3) = 0 then '**' end||'memo '||rownum memo
from xmlTable ('1 to 9'); 

create or replace trigger t1FullProofOnDelete
before delete on t1 for each row
when (substr (old.memo, 1, 2) = '**') 
begin
    raise_application_error (-20000, 'wrong deletion');
end;
/
delete from t1 where id=9;
```

Ожидаемая ошибка при удалении по условию:

> ORA-20000: wrong deletion

При удалении без условия, как и ожидалось, будут удалены 6 записей, а записи с исключениями останутся и запишутся в таблицу логгирования ошибок:

```sql
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 't1');

delete from t1 
log errors reject limit unlimited; 

6 rows deleted.

select t1.id, t1.memo, regexp_substr (ora_err_mesg$, '.*$', 1, 1, 'm') err 
from t1 join err$_t1 e on e.id = t1.id;

ID MEMO     ERR                         
-- -------- ----------------------------
 3 **memo 3 ORA-20000: wrong deletion   
 6 **memo 6 ORA-20000: wrong deletion   
 9 **memo 9 ORA-20000: wrong deletion
```