# Почему в Oracle PL/SQL во время удаления строк при срабатывании триггера транзакция удаления откатывается полностью и как этого избежать?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер, transaction

У меня в Oracle PL/SQL есть такая таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это таблица выстрелов. У меня есть люди, которые участвуют в соревновании по меткости в стрельбе. Колонка name описывает имя стрелка, колонка x показывает координату точки попадения пули x, а колонка y показывает координату точки попадения пули y. Мне необходимо удалить все строки, в которых значение y принимает значение 25. Вот как выглядит запрос на удаление строк:

```
DELETE FROM shots
WHERE y = 25;
```

Однако, у меня есть одно ограничение: если у меня x < 120, то удалять строку нельзя. Для этого я написал такой триггер:

```
create or replace trigger delet_shot
    after DELETE on shots
    for each row
begin
    if (:old.x > 120) then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Стрелок не попал в мишень');
    end if;
end;
```

Как вы уже могли заметить, у меня в таблице три строки, у которых y > 120. И лишь несколько из них я могу удалить, так как у них x > 120. Когда я пишу запрос на удаление строк, где y = 25, у меня транзакция вообще не выполняется. То есть не удаляются те строки, которые должны удаляться и не подпадают под триггеры. Скажите, как это исправить и сделать так, чтобы триггер не ругался и позволял удалять нужные строки. Возможен ли вариант использования языка транзакций?

Comment: Псмотрите, [ответ в ранее заданном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1058562/217579) поможет вам с решением?

Comment: Не совсем понял суть. Можете, пожалуйста, продемонстрировать это на моём примере? Спасибо!

Comment: А что конкретно не понятно? Наберите данные на [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06fbc52b4a314ceffd6630f18f3b8346) и дайте ссылку в комментарии, и я покажу на вашем примере.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрет на удаление записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1057629/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

Так проще ограничить сам запрос условием

```
DELETE FROM 
shots
WHERE 
y = 25 and
x >= 120;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для Oracle ошибки удаления из таблицы можно обрабатывать следующим образом:

Создаём таблицу логов ошибок для таблицы:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG(DML_TABLE_NAME => 'shots');
END;
```

Далее удаляем следующим образом:

```
DELETE FROM shots
WHERE y = 25
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_shots('DELETE')
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Comment: Вы проверили ваше решение? Оно даст ошибку.

Comment: Извините, некорректно написал. Исправил. Проверьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Да, спасибо, так будет работать. Пожалуйста, в следующий раз проверяйте решение до публикации ответа, например [на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4389fa8ac3272478b2567d9c0fd96f2d).

Comment: Кстати, подобное решение было предложено автору (см. комментарии под вопросом), но он его почему то не понял.